# How can i read from a text file line by line and add those strings to an array?

Tags: c#, io

I want to read two numbers from a text file: 2,5(Line one is 2, line 2 is 5 int my text file). I am trying to solve this for hours but each time i run the code it causes an error at this line

```
 citaj[o] = int.Parse(h);
```

This is my full code for the button. I also had some error while putting it out in the richtextbox line by line.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int p = 4;
        int i = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int x = 0;
        TextBox[] text = new TextBox[50];
        string[] linije = new string[50];
        string[] brojac = new string[10];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            text[1] = textBox1;
            text[2] = textBox2;
            text[3] = textBox3;
            brojac[0] = p.ToString();
            brojac[1] = c.ToString();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"text\brojac.txt", brojac);
            if (b == 0)
            {

                for (i = c; i <= p; i++)
                {
                    if ((i == c) && (x == 0))
                    {
                        linije[i] = "---------------";
                        x = 1;
                    }

                    else if (i == p)
                    {
                        linije[i] = "------------------";
                        b = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (x)
                        {
                            case 3: linije[i] ="Sifra:" + " " + text[3].Text;
                                x = 0;
                                break;
                            case 2: linije[i] ="Korisnicko ime:" + " " + text[2].Text;
                                x = 3;
                                break;
                            case 1: linije[i] ="Naziv:" + " " + text[1].Text;
                                x = 2;
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if(b == 1) 
            {
                c = c + 5;
                p = p + 5;
                b = 0;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"text\Kontener.txt", linije);
            }



        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int o = 0;
            string h;
            int[] citaj = new int[2];
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"text\brojac.txt");
            while ((h = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] parts = h.Split(',');
                citaj[0] = int.Parse(parts[0]);
                citaj[1] = int.Parse(parts[1]);
            }
            richTextBox1.Lines = new string[] { citaj[0].ToString(), citaj[1].ToString() };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ReadLine reads the full line till the newline. If you have 2,5 on the same line then you cant Parse 2,5 as an integer.

Comment: BTW: You'll get an exception at `richTextBox1.Lines[g] = citaj[g].ToString();` too when you get there....

Comment: `var yourArr = File.ReadAllLines(@"text\brojac.txt");`

Comment: citaj variable are declared? The size of array are greater then the number of lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array isnt initialized.

Try using List instead of array.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> citaj = new List<int>();
    string h;
    using(System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"text\brojac.txt")) 
    {
        while ((h = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            int number = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(h, out number)) 
                citaj.Add(number);
        } 
    } 
}
```